# gcloud app engine error while deploying the Web-app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, deployment, gcloud

The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:

> Failed to copy file.

Showing this error while deploying the application on to the Google cloud platform.

```
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxxx.appspot.com/9da4e24cec2641fdeaff4b1d6c3b3d88bcf1c524 failed with: Failed to copy file.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Failed to copy file.",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxxxx.appspot.com/9da4e24cec2641fdeaff4b1d6c3b3d88bcf1c524",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to generate the URL and run the project using https://xxxxx.appspot.com

I have tried deleting the file `9da4e24cec2641fdeaff4b1d6c3b3d88bcf1c524` from the bucket `staging.xxxxx.appspot.com` and then run again the `gcloud app deploy`, still not working.

Comment: Describe a bit the bigger picture: Where are your deploying from and how exactly? Can you show your `app.yaml` file? Do you have a `skip_files` section? What GAE environment?

Comment: 'runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app'

@DanCornilescu this is app.yaml

Comment: Recommend posting your question updates as edits to your original question, especially with regard to formatting the code snippets like your `app.yaml` to help others looking at your question for the first time.